# Entity Framework add item

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can i append key item in model

```
public class ModelOne 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is it possible to add key for example

```
db.ModelOne.Where(a => a.FirstName == "John").AddKeyItem("isYoung", true);
```

Comment: you have to assign the result of your query

Comment: You need to add to the `DbSet`.

Comment: Is it possible to attach key for example when i get item from db and i need to return as json format is it possible to attach key for example db.Model.Where(a => a.id == id).addKeyItem('isYoung', true')

Comment: @Guffy best way is probably create a dto or ViewModel for that object that contains IsYoung property, and give it to json serializer.